# Wrap net.IP in a custom type and add methodes in golang

Tags: go

I try to add methodes to net.IP. Therefore I created a custom type IPAddr:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net"
    "log"
)

func readNetworks(data []byte) (*[]Network, error) {
    var networks []Network

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &networks); err != nil {
        return &networks, err
    }

    return &networks, nil
}

type IPAddr net.IP

type Network struct {
    CIDR          string        `json:"cidr"`
    Gateway       IPAddr        `json:"gateway"`
}

func (ip *IPAddr) copy() IPAddr {
    if x := ip.To4(); x != nil {
        ip = x
    }
    dup := make(IPAddr, len(ip))
    copy(dup, ip)
    return dup
}

func main() {
    _, err := readNetworks([]byte("[{\"cidr\":\"10.100.19.0/24\",\"gateway\":\"10.100.19.1\"}]"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Some things that do not work here:

- Method To4() from net.IP is not known for IPAddr (line 27)
- len() does not work for IPAddr but for net.IP (line 30)
- string cannot be unmarshalled to IPAddr, this works for net.IP (line 12)

My type definition is obviously wrong... any hints?

See example at: 
http://play.golang.org/p/BT7VFnbPZW

Comment: Don't return pointers to slices, nor a `*IPAddr` (which is just a slice) as a receiver.

Comment: If that's the only "method" you want to add, then don't. Just use a function on `net.IP`. There is nothing superior about a method compared to a simple function in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Actually there more methods, that was just to illustrate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods are not inherited between types (Go does not have inheritance at all).

You may want to [embed](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) the type, if promoting the methods automatically is what you're after:

```
type IPAddr struct {
    net.IP
}
```

Comment: That is such an interesting feature of golang

Answer (score 3):

Convert to `net.IP` before trying to call methods, otherwise you'll call methods on the wrapper:

```
func (ip *IPAddr) copy() IPAddr {
    if x := net.IP(*ip).To4(); x != nil {
        ip = x
    }
    dup := make(IPAddr, len(net.IP(*ip)))
    copy(dup, *ip)
    return dup
}
```

For unmarshaling, implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) interface.

Another way to do it is by embedding `net.IP` in a struct, although this will inherit all methods from `net.IP`.